# Does Java support Input Methods written in Java?

Tags: java, ime

I'm reading about the [Java Input Method Framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imf/overview.html).  There is a tutorial for creating an [Input Method client](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/imf/api-tutorial.html#Creating%20Private%20Input%20Contexts) such as a text editor that interacts with the Input Method Editor.

[An old document](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/98au/java/jdk1.2beta4/docs/guide/intl/spec.html) (JDK 1.2, 1998) explains, "The framework is designed to be easily extended in a future JDK version to enable input methods written in the Java programming language."

In Android, there is a class [InputMethodService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method) for creating input method editors.

I'm assuming that standard desktop Java has not been extended with the functionality to create IMEs.  Am I missing something?  It looks like Java only supports native IMEs.